# What is the hexadecimal part in the Documents folder's path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have a file located in my app's `Documents` folder. When the app is terminated I save the file's URL in the AppDelegate's `applicationWillTerminate` method:

```
// archiver init code
[archiver encodeObject:file.URL forKey:kFileURL];
// finish encoding and write data to file system
```

But when trying to restore the file on the next app launch the file manager cannot locate the file: After calling

```
NSURL *fileURL = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:kFileURL];
NSString *filePath = fileURL.path;
```

the method

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExists:filePath];
```

returns `NO`.

I tried to find the reason for this and I discovered that the path to the `Documents` folder changes with every app launch. The part that changes is the hexadecimal folder in the middle. Here are two examples:

```
/private/var/mobile/Applications/04083A4A-87AC-4E3C-8BA1-F002B97AE304/Documents/...
/private/var/mobile/Applications/65D136BA-42C3-887A-B947-7FE396978153/Documents/...
```

I always thought that the hexadecimal part is some sort of ID unique to every app. But as it changes: What exactly is that number?
And how can I relocate my file then after terminating and relaunching my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just get the directory for the document folder and then load your file.

```
+ (NSString *)documentDataPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    if ([paths count] == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    if (directory == nil) {
        NSLog(@"NSDocumentDirectory not found!");
    }
    return directory;
}
```

Comment: After reading your simple answer I'm actually embarrassed I even asked that question. Of course I should not use absolute paths for saving and reading files when I can use the relative path instead. I have even done that several times in my app - I just didn't remember. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I'll mark it as the correct answer even if it does not answer the original question: I'm still curious what the hexadecimal path component represents and why it changes from app launch to app launch.

Comment: For those who might encounter the same problem in the future: For saving URLs it's best to use the bookmark capabilities of `NSURL`. You can read more about it in Apple's [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW10).